# java.lang.OutOfMemory Exception with Multithreaded Image Generate

Tags: multithreading, scala, out-of-memory, javax.imageio

I am trying to copy a lot of images with Java `ImageIO`. Each copy resizes the original picture. As the size of image set is huge (60,000). I try to use multi thread to solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
package generate.image

import scala.util.Random._
import scala.math._
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, TimeUnit, Executors}
import java.awt.Image
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

class ImageResizer{
    def resizeImage(srcImgPath: String, distImgPath: String, width: Int, height: Int){
        val srcFile: File = new File(srcImgPath)
        val srcImg: Image = ImageIO.read(srcFile)
        val buffImg: BufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)

        buffImg.getGraphics().drawImage(
                srcImg.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0,
                0, null
            )
        ImageIO.write(buffImg, "JPEG", new File(distImgPath))
    }
}

class ImageWorker(imgSrc: String, imgName: String, width: Int, height: Int) extends Runnable{
    override def run(): Unit = {
        val resizer = new ImageResizer()
        resizer.resizeImage(imgSrc, imgName, width, height);
    }
}

object ImageGenerate {

    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
        // parameters
        val dirName = args(0)
        val images = new File(dirName).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".JPEG"))
        val imgCnt = images.length


        // threadpool
        val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25)


        // copy with norm
        for(i <- 0 until imgCnt){
            for(cnt <- 1 to 20){
                val width = nextInt(200) + 300
                val height = nextInt(200) + 300
                val imgSrc: String = images(i).getAbsolutePath
                val imgName: String = "img/%s_%d_%d_%d.JPEG".format(splitFilename(images(i).getName), width, height, cnt)
                pool.execute(new ImageWorker(imgSrc, imgName, width, height))
            }
        }


        pool.shutdown()
        pool.awaitTermination(Long.MaxValue, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    }

    // split file name
    def splitFilename(fileName: String) = {
        fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."))
    }

}
```

`ImageResizer` does the copy work. It reads an image into `BufferedImage`, resizes it into a new `BufferedImage`, and finally writes to a `JPEG` file.

`ImageWorker` does the thread work. It is executed by the worker threads in the `ExecuteServive`.

`ImageGenerate` does the dispatching work. It reads all the image files in the `args(0)` (first arg), generates new random width and height, and submit a new job to `pool`.

Compile and run: `scalac ImageGenerate.scala` `scala generate.image.ImageGenerate test`. The sizes of images are 150kb in average.

As is running, the program throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.
[image: Error Image]
Sometimes, there is a `Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-36" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` error.

If I set the parameter `-J-Xmx2048m`, the program will run smoothly. However, I only run 400 images. Is there any optimization for my code?

Thanks for sharing your idea, best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling [dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose())

Something like this (untested)

```
  val graphics = buffImg.getGraphics()
  graphics.drawImage(
    srcImg.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0,
    0, null
  )
  ImageIO.write(buffImg, "JPEG", new File(distImgPath))
  graphics.dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. I think my submissions of tasks to thread-pool is not flow-controlled. And memory runs out when there exist too many tasks waiting in the `ExecuteService`. Therefore, I use a semaphore to limit the speed of submissions. And it works a lot.